# Error Creating A Table(org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL) and java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am attempting to contruct an Order table in a MySQL database, but I'm getting a CommapndAcceptanceException and java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorExceptionwhenever the application runs and I am unable to see the table created in the database. However an order_seq table to generate the id does successfully get created, so I am a bit confused.

Order Entity :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer orderNumber;
    private LocalDate orderDate;
    private LocalDate requireDate;
    private LocalDate shippedDate;
    private String text;
    private Status status; //Spring AttributeConverter automatically converts the type from : Entity <-> DB column representation

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_number")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

this order entity has ManyToOne *unidirectional* mapping to a Customer Entity

Customer Entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer customerNumber;
    private String customerName;
    private String contactLastName;
    private String contactFirstName;
    private String phone;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
    private double creditLimit;
}
```

Also, I'm facing the same issue with the Payment entity receiving the sameCommandAcceptanceException with an error on SQL syntax. It could be coming from the foreign key contrainst as I'm currently learning how to map entities.

Payment Entity :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Payment {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PaymentId paymentId;
    private LocalDate paymentDate;
    private double amount;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("customerNumber") //this specifies the attribute in the composite primary key to which the relationship attribute corresponds to
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") //Unidirectional relationship with Customer(Actually don't need @JoinColumn but can specify a name)
    private Customer customer;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class PaymentId implements Serializable {

    private Integer customerNumber;
    private String checkNumber;
}
```

application.properties :

```
spring.application.name=order_owl

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order_owl
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

After renaming the Order Entity as "order" is a keyword in SQL, my order table is being created successfully in the database. However, I'm still receiving these errors. Is this an issue?

```
   Hibernate: 
    alter table _order 
       drop 
       foreign key FK2fa68ooqiyef95u1lc31wteje
2024-03-23T12:38:22.381-07:00  WARN 38844 --- [order_owl] [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table _order 
       drop 
       foreign key FK2fa68ooqiyef95u1lc31wteje" via JDBC [Table 'order_owl._order' doesn't exist]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table _order 
       drop 
       foreign key FK2fa68ooqiyef95u1lc31wteje" via JDBC [Table 'order_owl._order' doesn't exist]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:470) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplication.main(OrderOwlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'order_owl._order' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:770) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

Hibernate: 
    alter table payment 
       drop 
       foreign key FKby2skjf3ov608yb6nm16b49lg
2024-03-23T12:38:22.387-07:00  WARN 38844 --- [order_owl] [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table payment 
       drop 
       foreign key FKby2skjf3ov608yb6nm16b49lg" via JDBC [Table 'order_owl.payment' doesn't exist]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table payment 
       drop 
       foreign key FKby2skjf3ov608yb6nm16b49lg" via JDBC [Table 'order_owl.payment' doesn't exist]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:470) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplication.main(OrderOwlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'order_owl.payment' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:770) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists _order
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists _order_seq
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists customer
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists customer_seq
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists payment
Hibernate: 
    create table _order (
        customer_number integer,
        order_date date,
        order_number integer not null,
        require_date date,
        shipped_date date,
        status varchar(255),
        text varchar(255),
        primary key (order_number)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table _order_seq (
        next_val bigint
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    insert into _order_seq values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 
    create table customer (
        credit_limit float(53) not null,
        customer_number integer not null,
        address_line1 varchar(255),
        address_line2 varchar(255),
        city varchar(255),
        contact_first_name varchar(255),
        contact_last_name varchar(255),
        country varchar(255),
        customer_name varchar(255),
        phone varchar(255),
        postal_code varchar(255),
        state varchar(255),
        primary key (customer_number)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table customer_seq (
        next_val bigint
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    insert into customer_seq values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 
    create table payment (
        amount float(53) not null,
        customer_id integer not null,
        payment_date date,
        check_number varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (customer_id, check_number)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    alter table _order 
       add constraint FK2fa68ooqiyef95u1lc31wteje 
       foreign key (customer_number) 
       references customer (customer_number)
Hibernate: 
    alter table payment 
       add constraint FKby2skjf3ov608yb6nm16b49lg 
       foreign key (customer_id) 
       references customer (customer_number)
2024-03-23T12:38:22.666-07:00  INFO 38844 --- [order_owl] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-23T12:38:22.699-07:00  WARN 38844 --- [order_owl] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-03-23T12:38:23.012-07:00  INFO 38844 --- [order_owl] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-03-23T12:38:23.021-07:00  INFO 38844 --- [order_owl] [           main] dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplication   : Started OrderOwlApplication in 3.555 seconds (process running for 3.857)
```

Comment: *order* is a keyword in sql. Rename the table.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you that removed some of the errors.